Git in Cygwin doesn't take daylight savings time (DST) into account
I'm using Git 2.46.2.windows.1 on my Windows 11 PC where I use GNU Bash version 5.2.21(1)-release (x86_64-pc-cygwin) provided by Cygwin 3.5.4 (64-bit version).
My timezone is Europe/Brussels where currently daylight savings time (DST) is active; my timezone currently is CEST.
When I commit in PowerShell, all dates are as I expect: Executing git log prints AuthorDate and CommitDate with the expected timezone +0200:
PS C:\Users\StevenVolckaert\Repos\stevenvolckaert\test-repo> git commit -m "Initial commit"
[main (root-commit) 76da599] Initial commit
 1 file changed, 26 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
PS C:\Users\StevenVolckaert\Repos\stevenvolckaert\test-repo> git log --pretty=fuller
commit 76da5992307b39acc1ccdcd6258a4e395a4cbd95 (HEAD -> main)
Author:     Steven Volckaert <steven.volckaert@foobar.com>
AuthorDate: Thu Oct 3 10:39:44 2024 +0200
Commit:     Steven Volckaert <steven.volckaert@foobar.com>
CommitDate: Thu Oct 3 10:39:44 2024 +0200

    Initial commit
PS C:\Users\StevenVolckaert\Repos\stevenvolckaert\test-repo>

When I git log in Bash, I get the same results.
However, when I commit in Bash, 1 hour is substracted from AuthorDate and CommitDate and the timezone is printed as +0100:
~/Repos/stevenvolckaert/test-repo$ git commit -m "Add .gitattributes"
[main e6fe6e7] Add .gitattributes
 1 file changed, 269 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitattributes
~/Repos/stevenvolckaert/test-repo$
~/Repos/stevenvolckaert/test-repo$ git log --pretty=fuller
commit e6fe6e7b9162a34f8e09845d781bc545e9a67e26 (HEAD -> main)
Author:     Steven Volckaert <steven.volckaert@foobar.com>
AuthorDate: Thu Oct 3 09:47:05 2024 +0100
Commit:     Steven Volckaert <steven.volckaert@foobar.com>
CommitDate: Thu Oct 3 09:47:05 2024 +0100

    Add .gitattributes

commit 76da5992307b39acc1ccdcd6258a4e395a4cbd95
Author:     Steven Volckaert <steven.volckaert@foobar.com>
AuthorDate: Thu Oct 3 10:39:44 2024 +0200
Commit:     Steven Volckaert <steven.volckaert@foobar.com>
CommitDate: Thu Oct 3 10:39:44 2024 +0200

    Initial commit
~/Repos/stevenvolckaert/test-repo$

How can I fix this?
Some of my PC's diagnostics below:
~/Repos/stevenvolckaert/test-repo$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
~/Repos/stevenvolckaert/test-repo$ echo $TZ
Europe/Brussels
~/Repos/stevenvolckaert/test-repo$ date
Thu, Oct  3, 2024 10:48:55 AM
~/Repos/stevenvolckaert/test-repo$

My PC's locale is set to en-US because I perfer this language over Dutch for computer programs. Overriding the LC_ALL or LC_TIME environment variables for the git commit command (explained here) doesn't have the desired effect: The date/times still are formatted as +0100.
~/Repos/stevenvolckaert/test-repo$ LC_ALL=en_BE git commit --amend --no-edit --reset-author --date=now
[main d193abd] Add .gitattributes
 Date: Thu Oct 3 09:52:48 2024 +0100
 1 file changed, 269 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitattributes
~/Repos/stevenvolckaert/test-repo$ git log --pretty=fuller
commit d193abd6bb8cb93f47fc9cfb16d908538bf79e5f (HEAD -> main)
Author:     Steven Volckaert <steven.volckaert@foobar.com>
AuthorDate: Thu Oct 3 09:52:48 2024 +0100
Commit:     Steven Volckaert <steven.volckaert@foobar.com>
CommitDate: Thu Oct 3 09:52:48 2024 +0100

    Add .gitattributes

commit 76da5992307b39acc1ccdcd6258a4e395a4cbd95
Author:     Steven Volckaert <steven.volckaert@foobar.com>
AuthorDate: Thu Oct 3 10:39:44 2024 +0200
Commit:     Steven Volckaert <steven.volckaert@foobar.com>
CommitDate: Thu Oct 3 10:39:44 2024 +0200

    Initial commit
~/Repos/stevenvolckaert/test-repo$

Many thanks!
Edit 1 - Monday 7 October 2024
To answer Doug Henderson's comments, I pushed my test repo to GitHub. There, times of both commits are formatted as GMT+2 (as expected for my account settings).
git version is 2.46.2.windows.1 both in Cygwin Bash as in PowerShell 7.4.5:
~/Repos/stevenvolckaert/test-repo$ git version
git version 2.46.2.windows.1
~/Repos/stevenvolckaert/test-repo$

PowerShell 7.4.5
PS C:\Users\StevenVolckaert> git version
git version 2.46.2.windows.1
PS C:\Users\StevenVolckaert>

And the git command in both point to the same binary:
~/Repos/stevenvolckaert/test-repo$ which git
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/cmd/git
~/Repos/stevenvolckaert/test-repo$

PS C:\Users\StevenVolckaert> (get-command git).Path
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
PS C:\Users\StevenVolckaert>


Please put your test-repo on a public git hub server, such as Github, and post a link to the test-repo there. I would like to see what the logs there show. Also, show us the the results of git version in both Powershell and bash

Hi @DougHenderson, thank you for your comment. I've updated my question with Edit 1 - Monday 7 October 2024.
